# md-sidenav fold left delay, looking for a replacement for transform

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material, sidebar

Im working with angular-material md-sidenav element, it's on the left side and when i click on it it fold left. this closing/folding action is done with css transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0), but after reading about it i understand that in order to save resources it 'freeze' the element as an image during the transform, this cause a delay for about a second(i think), visible to the user. i am looking for a replacement with the same folding animation.
i added  position:relative style to the md-sidenav,it gave the element the behavior i needed but it's in the core if this issue.

html:

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl" layout="column" style="height: 100%;" ng-cloak>
  <section layout="row" flex>
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left"
                md-disable-backdrop md-whiteframe="4" style="position: relative;">
      <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo">
        <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Disabled Backdrop</h1>
      </md-toolbar>
      <md-content layout-margin>
      </md-content>
    </md-sidenav>
    <md-content flex >
    <md-toolbar layout="row">
      testing123
    </md-toolbar>
      <div layout="column" layout-align="top center" style="background-color:#ff5252;">
        <div>
          <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()" class="md-raised">
            Toggle Sidenav
          </md-button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </md-content>
  </section>
</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav) {
    $scope.toggleLeft = buildToggler('left');
    $scope.toggleRight = buildToggler('right');
   function buildToggler(componentId) {
      return function() {
        $mdSidenav(componentId).toggle();
      }
    }    
});
```

css:

```
.md-sidenav-left.md-closed, md-sidenav.md-closed {
  //original angular-matireal code
     -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0) !important; 
     transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0) !important;
     /* my tempoory solution */
     /* -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) !important; 
     transform: translate3d(0,0,0) !important; */
     }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/340/

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution/walk around for now using margin-left, position:absolute and transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out/ease-out.

html:

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl" layout="column" style="height: 100%;" ng-cloak>
  <section layout="row" flex>
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left sidenav-container" md-component-id="left"
                md-disable-backdrop md-whiteframe="4" >
      <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo">
        <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Disabled Backdrop</h1>
      </md-toolbar>
      <md-content layout-margin>
      </md-content>
    </md-sidenav>
    <md-content flex class="delay-fix-md-content" ng-class="{'walk-around-sidenav-collapse':(isToggleSidenav === true)}">
    <md-toolbar layout="row">
      testing123
    </md-toolbar>
      <div layout="column" layout-align="top center" style="background-color:#ff5252;">
        <div>
          <md-button ng-click="toggleSidenav('left')" class="md-raised">
            Toggle Sidenav
          </md-button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </md-content>
  </section>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.delay-fix-md-content{
  margin-left:320px !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out !important;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out !important;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out !important;
}
.walk-around-sidenav-collapse{
  margin-left:0px !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out !important;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out !important;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out !important;
}
.sidenav-container{
  position: absolute; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out !important;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out !important;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out !important;
}
```

js:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav) {
        $scope.isToggleSidenav = true;
    $scope.toggleSidenav = function (menuId) {
        $mdSidenav(menuId).toggle();
        $scope.isToggleSidenav = !$scope.isToggleSidenav;
    };

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/342/